# ADC readings problem: built in vs external ADC unit

Tags: adc, breadboard

Why am I getting these (mostly) good readings with the built in ADC of the Arduino Uno (10 bits resolution):

[image]

and these scattered values (same analog sensor used) with the external [LTC1418](http://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1418fa.pdf) ADC (14 bits resolution of which the last 2 bits were dropped) ?

[image]

For what is worth, the sensor is an [G-NSDOG1-006](http://www.te.com/commerce/DocumentDelivery/DDEController?Action=srchrtrv&DocNm=DOG1_MEMS-Series_Inclinometer&DocType=DS&DocLang=English)
Also I once had this anomalous outcome from the built in ADC:

[image]

I am using the external ADC as shown in "Figure 24. Internal Conversion Clock Selected. Data Transferred After Conversion Using an External SCLK." at page 25 of the spreadsheet above. All of the readings were taken at every 0.5 seconds.

The electrical schematic is what they recommend in the same document:

[image]

The LTC1418 chip is soldered to a SSOP-to-DIP adapter PCB which is inserted into a solderless  breadboard.

My final goal is to stabilize the external ADC unit (the LTC1418 chip)'s output.

Thanks!

**edit1**

In response to @Brian Drummond

Good thinking!

- For the supposedly stable 3v3 output from the arduino and USB power
  the jitter stays within 11 units.
- For the supposedly stable 3v3 output from the arduino and battery
  power the jitter stays within 6 units.
- For the GND and USB power the jitter stays within 5 units.
- For the GND and battery power the jitter stays within 5 units.

Comment: Did you put the capacitors as close to the chip as possible?

Comment: @Gerben Yes I did. Although they are THTs on an 100 mil spaced breadboard. And tehre is a bit more copper trace on the SSOP-tto-DIP adapter, hmm...

Comment: Divide and conquer. If you ground the ADC input or wire it to a suitable (and well decoupled) DC voltage, what does the ADC output look like?

Comment: Also. why is there such a big DC offset on the external one? (519 is approximately 512 or 0.5* full scale on 10 bit, 2500 is well above 2048 or half scale on 12 bit. One suspect : wrong or noisy reference voltage on the external?

Comment: @BrianDrummond edited the question. As for your second remark, are you talking about V_REF ? That one is connected as shown in the diagram, no mistake there.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using external 16-bit ADCs with Arduino, e.g. LTC1859.  You need short leads to the ADC otherwise SPI will get noisy and lead to data corruption.  If you are not already doing it, a PCB with routed and shielded traces also helps keep down the analog noise.  Use a clean voltage source instead of USB.

According to the data sheet for your sensor, new data are available much faster than you need (10 ms vs. your 500 ms).  You can take advantage of this to minimize effects of noise by signal averaging - e.g. moving average, or taking average of blocks of data every 0.5 s.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a grounding problem (noisy SPI) Pay attention to the analog and digital ground leads and avoid sharing the two in a single connection to the Arduino. bringing all the grounds to a point (close the Arduino) is a good place to start.